# Is there anyway to make this code faster?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a code here that automatically tick a box when all three boxes are true, however this is taking forever to load as I have thousands of boxes in the sheet, is there any way to make this code quicker?

at the moment the code is making everything lag and unresponsive

```
function checkBox(j,k,l,m,result){ 
 
  var result = true;

  if ( j === true && k === true & l === true && m === true) {
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }

  return result;

}
```

[if the first four boxes are tick, then box number 6 will automatically tick, but it's taking forever to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NgZG.png)

Comment: Don't present code as an image. Type it in your question.

Comment: It is not this function that is taking forever, as this is about as simple as it can get. You are better off looking into the functions that call this one (and supply the parameters) to try and find the bottleneck

Comment: I feel like because there are thousand of boxes that needs to be checked it's making the entire sheet unresponsive @about14sheep

Comment: And you might be right, but that has nothing to do with this particular function.

Comment: why is result a parameter in the function which you then redefine?

Comment: @dave110022 I needed to redefine it as I need to assign a cell to it

Comment: a cell?  what do you mean?   Are you using a <table> as I did - probably the simplest way to go with so many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing wrong, but this code took 46ms for 10,000 lines - a little longer to render on the screen.

```
function go(){

    //set up a test table with every 10th row with all boxes ticked
    let str="<table>";
    for (let i=0;i<10000;i++){
        str +="<tr>";
        for (let j=0;j<4;j++){
            str +="<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
        }
        str +="<td> </td><td><input type='checkbox'</td>";
        str +="</tr>";
    }
    str +="</table>";

    container.innerHTML=str;


    //start here to compute the result column

    let start=(new Date()).getTime();
    let table=container.querySelector("table");
    let rows=table.querySelectorAll("tr");

    for (let i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        let inputs=rows[i].querySelectorAll("input");
        if(i%10==0){
            for (let j=0;j<4;j++)inputs[j].checked=true;
        }
        else {
            for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) inputs[j].checked = true;
            }
        }
        inputs[4].checked=inputs[0].checked && inputs[1].checked && inputs[2].checked && inputs[3].checked;
    }

    alert((new Date()).getTime()-start);
}
```